# Type-parametrized class with default type parameter

Tags: scala

For example, I have the following class hierarchy:

```
abstract class A {
  def a() {}
  def aa()
}

class B extends A {
  def aa() {}
  def b()
}

class C extends A {
  def aa() {}
  def c()
}
```

And then I want to create a class that can store a collection of any combination of these classes instances. It will be able to call common methods. And due to type parametrization it must provide the ability to call class-specific methods if parametrized with these classes during the creation:

```
object Group {

  def apply(as: Buffer[A]) = new Group[A](as)
  def apply[T <: A](as: Buffer[T]) = new Group[T](as)
}

class Group[T <: A](as: Buffer[T]) {

  def a() { as.map(_.a()) }
  def aa() { as.map(_.aa()) }

}
```

so the `Group` can be created with the default, most generic type parameter like this:

```
val groupA = Group(Buffer[A]())
groupA.a()  //ok
groupA.aa() //ok
groupA.b()  //error
groupA.c()  //error
```

and it can be created when parametrized explicitly with one of the descendants of `A`:

```
val groupB = Group[B](Buffer[B]())
groupB.a()  //ok
groupB.aa() //ok
groupB.b()  //ok
groupB.c()  //error
```

and if it is possible, I would like to somehow remove the unnecessary type specification of `[B]` when creating the group, since it can be extracted from the passed buffer type:

```
val groupB = Group(Buffer[B]())
```

What is the correct way of realization of this functionality? Is it possible? Maybe there is a better architectural decision to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:** the code here is pseudocode, I just don't know how to write what I want.

**UPDATE 2:** I guess that calling type-specific methods like `b()` or `c()` should be realized through mapping:

```
groupC.as.map(_.c())
```

which is *only* possible, if the type parametrization is correct. That gets closer to my idea, but the exact possible way of realization remains a mystery (aside from a bunch of usages of `asInstanceOf` things)..

Comment: Maybe use implicit conversion of your `Group[C]` to something that has a `c()` method, which is only applicable when the parameter is `C`?

Comment: @ziggystar: maybe, but could you please show an example of this? I am not sure I can grasp it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use implicit conversions to seemingly add methods to only those instances of `Group` which are parameterized with the correct type. This can be considered a selective version of the [pimp my library](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala+pimp+my+library) pattern.

```
scala> abstract class A { def a() {}; def aa() {} }
defined class A

scala> class B extends A {def b() {}}
defined class B

scala> class C extends A {def c() {}}
defined class C
```

Now I define the `Group` class. Take note on the implicit conversion for `Group[C]` that adds the `c()` method. This conversion is not applicaple to e.g. a `Group[A]` value.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Group[T <: A](as: Seq[T])
object Group{implicit def forC(gc: Group[C]) = new {def c() {gc.as.map(_.c())}}}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Group
defined module Group
```

Now let's see if it works.

```
scala> val groupC = Group(new C :: new C :: Nil)
groupC: Group[C] = Group(List(C@7f144c75, C@da7d681))

scala> groupC.c()  //works

scala> val groupB = Group(new B :: new B :: Nil)
groupB: Group[B] = Group(List(B@e036122, B@7fde065d))

scala> groupB.c()  //fails as expected
<console>:16: error: value c is not a member of Group[B]
              groupB.c()
                     ^
```

Comment: That is definitely much better! But, sorry, I have some questions =) : 1) case class Group is only made *case* class because of the convinience of calling the automatically created `as` method? 2) you have mentioned that the `c()` method does not yield anything. why is this important? did you mean that it is purely side-effet and this cannot be helped? 3) where can I read more about the `implicit` form that you have used here, with the `new {}` construct for a nameless class? Does this form automatically mean that the nameless class instance (?) will inherit what's there in Group[C]?

Comment: 1) `case` class is convenience; it also adds the `apply` to the companion, which you did manually. 2) Yes, the comment is a bit misleading. I added it so a reader does not wonder where the output is. There's none since the method does nothing. You can do whatever you like in `c()`. 3) The pattern is called [*Pimp my library*](http://www.scalaclass.com/node/14); you can also name the class. And it does not inherit things from `C` unless you add a `extends C`.